# how to set woocommerce product color attribute programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How can i change woocommerce product color attribute programmatically ?
I use this code but only delete color attribute value!

```
$product = wc_get_product($product_ID);
        $product->set_attributes(array(
            'pa_color' => 'red'
        ));
        $product->save();
```

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

i found the solution

```
wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $color, 'pa_color', true );
        $att_color = array(
            'pa_color' => array(
                'name'        => 'pa_color',
                'value'       => $color,
                'is_visible'  => '1',
                'is_taxonomy' => '1'
            )
        );

        update_post_meta( $product_id, '_product_attributes', $att_color );
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me. BTW this can be used to add multiple attributes at once, by adding more arrays within the $att_color array (which I would rename to something more generic like $attrs), and using wp_set_object_terms for each attribute.